# Serialize a DOM range

Tags: javascript, dom, serialization, range

is there any standard/easy way to serialize a [DOM Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) (and the IE equivalent) with java script.

The motivation is to store the current selection for a document together with its HTML code.

---

I thought of using XPath for it, but before I start to reinventing the wheel maybe there is something already working available and I just haven't found it (best would be a jQuery based solution).

Comment: When do you want to deserialize it? A Range means little without the document in which it exists.

Comment: After the serialized document is deserialized.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got the answer visit link below :
[Rangy, A cross-browser JavaScript range and selection library](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/serializer.html)

Answer (score 0):

There have been a few times I would have found something like this useful and I don't know of anything that currently exists. XPath seems the logical choice to me.